# Как настроить ПК под сервер, удаленный доступ через интернет?

Tags: sql, postgresql, сервер

Как сделать из ПК сервер (postgreSQL)? Я не очень в плане настройки серверов, поэтому буду благодарен за подробные шаги. Сервер PostgreSQL создан как localHost с портом 5432, но я хочу что бы сервер был доступен через интернет. Удаленный доступ на компьютере разрешен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Картинки с текстом сохраняйте в формате png. В jpg текст сильно расплывается.

Answer (score 4):

*Просьба отнестись к данному ответу с пониманием. Тут две проблемы - первая, это опасность действия, которое вы хотите предпринять, вторая - огромное количество тонких нюансов выставления сервера в интернет, особенно когда речь идет о SOHO-доступе - с его NAT и серым айпишником.*

То что вы включили удаленный рабочий стол (первый скрин) не имеет абсолютно никакого отношения к postgres и открывает дыру в безопасности.

Более того, сокет постгреса, торчащий "наголо" в интернет, также является огромной дырой в безопасности, как минимум потому, что будет гнать данные (а при некоторых настройках, логины и пароли) в нешифрованном виде.

Знаете, сколько проектов поплатились репутацией из-за баз (*в том числе и разработческих, потому что при таких низких компетенциях, разарботческая база - это дамп прода*), которые торчали нагишом в интернетик?

Базу следует выставлять для удаленного доступа или через SSL, или через [SSH](https://habr.com/ru/post/81607/) или через VPN.

Даже в целях тестирования не следует открывать доступ к базе "просто так".

Теперь, после этого длительного дисклеймера, отвечу на ваш вопрос - но вы делаете это **на свой страх и риск**.

Вам нужно заставить постгрес слушать не только локалхост, но и всех подряд (авторы программы заботятся о безопасности, а вы - нет). Для этого нужно изменить `pg_hba.conf`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

заменить там 127.0.0.1/32 на 0.0.0.0/0

Кроме того, если машина находится за NAT (а большинство домашних машин находятся за NAT, и не одним) - вам нужно организовать проброс портов и иметь белый IP.

Простой признак, что вы находитесь за NAT - у вашего компьютера будет адрес типа 192.168.X.X или 10.X.X.X

А если ваш внешний IP еще и динамический (что тоже не редкость), вам понадобится еще и DynDNS организовать.

Comment: Спасибо за предупреждение, я пожалуй лучше подробнее изучу всю эту шляпу