# Подключение к бд на удаленном компьютере

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, golang, visual-studio-code, remote-access

На домашнем ноуте под Ubuntu 20.04 у меня есть Golang, Postgresql и VSCode.
Допустим что в постгресе есть юзер postgres с паролем password, под его именем создана таблица books и я хочу из кода Go получить строки из этой таблицы. В коде я делаю

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type Book struct {
    isbn   string
    title  string
    author string
    price  float32
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://password@localhos/books")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM books")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()

    bks := make([]*Book, 0)
    for rows.Next() {
        bk := new(Book)
        err := rows.Scan(&bk.isbn, &bk.title, &bk.author, &bk.price)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        bks = append(bks, bk)
    }
    if err = rows.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, bk := range bks {
        fmt.Printf("%s, %s, %s, £%.2f\n", bk.isbn, bk.title, bk.author, bk.price)
    }
}
```

и таким образом я без проблем получаю необходимые значения из таблицы при `go run main.go` в терминале.
Но что, если ноут, на котором находится база с таблицей, подключен к роутеру, который получает ip 93.x.x.x. Я хочу описанный код применить на удаленном компьютере. То есть получить строки из таблицы не с локалхоста а из другой вообще сети.
В строке

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://password@localhos/books")
```

логика подсказывает что localhost нужно поменять на 93.x.x.x
Но если, при измененной строке, я сделаю на удаленном компе `go run main.go`, то вместо значений из таблицы я получаю
`2021/04/08 13:11:48 dial tcp 93.x.x.x:5432: connect: connection refused exit status 1`

Я подозреваю что проблема возникает именно изза того что подключение осуществляется через роутер. Как бы настроить перенаправление трафика роутера чтобы я мог удаленно подключаться к свой бд и таблице?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Доступ к серверу из интернета](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523111/%d0%94%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: в дополнение к дубликату: демон, к которому нужен доступ, естественно, должен слушать не только внутренний ip 127.0.0.1, но и внешний ip-адрес компьютера (нет, не внешний адрес вашего маршрутизатора, а свой собственный внешний адрес, закреплённый за тем сетевым интерфейсом, через который происходит общение с маршрутизатором).

Comment: почему задуманное вами вообще-то плохая идея, неплохо изложено, например, в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1253505/178576

Comment: @aleksandr barakin согласен, что идея плохая, но мне требуется это для обучения работы с бд. Понятно что для своего сетевого приложения я не стал бы так делать

Comment: В том и проблема, что роутер уже настроен но все равно не получается подключиться к бд из интернета. И в настройках самого постгреса я уже проставил чтобы слушались все ip, так как в подробной инструкции к установке это есть.

Comment: ну, знаете, мы тут вряд ли сможем диагностировать сетевые проблемы, происходящие у вас. вам самому надо действовать.

Comment: Если есть ssh доступ к серверу, с которого нужен доступ можно воспользоваться reverse ssh tunnel.